# prop not displayed in react custom dropdown component

Tags: string, reactjs, dropdown, default-value, react-props

I'm facing a silly issue of the default value not being rendered in the form.
In my app, when the user is logged in, a form will be auto-filled with some of the details as it will fetch the data from the stored user information passed to my component through props.

In that case, my already selected 'Gender' i.e. the default value is not getting displayed when the component is rendered.

At the same time, when I passing the same value as hard-coded, it works perfectly fine.

I'm receiving the 'defaultValue' in 'renderGenderDropDown' as 'Male'(same as I stored in myValue const).

But, myValue const works, defaultValue doesn't.
And yes, my component is used in multiple other components and works perfectly fine. It basically, renders '' from 'React'.

What do I need to fix this?

### Code:

```
renderGender() {
    const { options, data } = this.props;
    const gender = get(data, 'gender');
    const defaultValue = gender ? capitalize(gender) : gender;
    const fieldName = 'gender';
    return this.renderGenderDropDown(fieldName, defaultValue, prefixOptions);
}

renderGenderDropDown(fieldName, defaultValue, options) {
    const { configuration, id, validations } = this.props;
    const myValue = 'Male';
    return  <AppDropDown
      label={getLabel(fieldName, configuration, validations, 'gender')}
      options={dropdownOptions}
      defaultValue={myValue}
      //defaultValue={defaultValue}
      key={fieldName}
      className={fieldName}
      disabled={false}
      id={id}
      onChange={this.onGenderChange(this[fieldName])}
    />
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting your logic here on this line: `const defaultValue = gender ? capitalize(gender) : gender;` You are using the variable `gender` if `gender` is not defined? shouldn't this be another default value if `gender` returns falsy?

Comment: Yes..gender could be not defined at times...when the user is not logged in...wgender will be undefined

Comment: if `gender` is undefined, how do you assign `gender` to `gender` ?

Comment: Ignore that ternary condition. Even if I pass 'capitalize(gender)', it is the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting the state with `defaultValue` and access this.state.defaultValue in your renderGenderDropdown?

Comment: Did you try console.log(gender) before calling this.renderGenderDropDown() to see if you are getting a valid data? Is your get() an asynchronous call?

Comment: Ur right...get seems to be an async call...how do I handle it with a promise then?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, there isnt a native `capitalize()` . This is probably returning back `undefined` instead of a string. Try this to capitalize the first letter in the string.

`gender.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + gender.substr(1)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using loads capitalize there...and it works fine..

Comment: The only other thing i can think of is the data you are retrieving isnt coming back how you are expecting it. Have you tried just passing in the gender without the conditional to see if that render.

Comment: then something must be wrong with the the data you are fetching. 

You can console.log(typeof gender) and verify it is a string.

Have you also tried passing the value 'Male' as a string. If that works then it is your data.

Comment: Yes, if u see in the code above, I passed myValue which is equivalent to 'Male' as defaultValue instead and it works fine.